# How to get and edit custom fields if in Quick Edit

Tags: custom-field, quick-edit

I've got some custom fields that I would like a user to be able to edit in Quick Edit, I can manage the columns but I'm unable to edit them if Quick Edit is clicked current code with custom fields I'd like to be able to edit:

```
/* custom columns */
add_filter("manage_edit-programmes_columns", "edit_columns" );
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column", "custom_columns");

function edit_columns($columns)
{
    $columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type ='checkbox' />",
        "title" => "Schedule id",
        "programme" => "Programme",
        "channel" => "Channel", 
        "onair" => "On Air", 
        "catchup" => "Catchup", 
        "popularity" => "Popularity", 
        "onair" => "On Air", 
        "date" => "Date"
    );
    return $columns;
}

function custom_columns( $column ) {

    global $post;

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case "programme":
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Programme Name', true);
            break;
        case "channel":
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'channelnames', '', ', ', '');
            break;
        case "onair":
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Date Time Start', true);
            break;
        case "catchup":
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'linktovideocatchup', true);
            break;
        case "popularity":
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'popularityfig', true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Here is the best tutorial I have found to date: [http://rachelcarden.com/2012/03/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/](http://rachelcarden.com/2012/03/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/)

Comment: The URL there is no longer correct (it gives a 404). I think it should be this one: https://wpdreamer.com/2012/03/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things,

1. Make sure in your `save_post` hook you're checking for `DOING_AJAX` which is used for saving in quick-edit.
2. Check out my other question: [Quick edit screen customization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/quick-edit-screen-customization). The answer I received worked, but I haven't actually implemented it into my plugin quite yet as it's not a priority of mine *yet*.

Hope that helps you out. ;)

Comment: eek! head spin, can't see how I add that to my custom_post_type and access my custom fields?

Comment: So I presume I need to change the form input Name and ID to match my custom field to make it work - right?

Comment: I personally haven't done this as I've stated in my answer. I was merely passing along the answer I received that looked like it might work. It hasn't been a priority of mine with my current project because it seems whenever something I want to do, something else comes up and I have to go fix that and I forget about the original thing I wanted to do. :/

Answer (score 1):

Saving data from Quick Edit and Bulk Edit need JavaScript helpers.

The following code comes out of a production system using the `video` custom post type before I wrote the the WordPress bulk edit plugin [Custom Bulk/Quick Edit](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulkquick-edit/).

**File `quick_edit.js`**

```
// @ref http://rachelcarden.com/2012/03/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/
(function($) {
    // we create a copy of the WP inline edit post function
    var $wp_inline_edit = inlineEditPost.edit;
    // and then we overwrite the function with our own code
    inlineEditPost.edit = function( id ) {
        // "call" the original WP edit function
        // we don't want to leave WordPress hanging
        $wp_inline_edit.apply( this, arguments );

        // now we take care of our business

        // get the post ID
        var $post_id = 0;
        if ( typeof( id ) == 'object' )
            $post_id = parseInt( this.getId( id ) );

        if ( $post_id > 0 ) {
            // define the edit row
            var $edit_row = $( '#edit-' + $post_id );
            var $post_row = $( '#post-' + $post_id );

            // get the data
            var $additional_copies = $( '.column-additional_copies', $post_row ).html();
            var $main_credits      = $( '.column-main_credits', $post_row ).html();

            // populate the data
            $( ':input[name="additional_copies"]', $edit_row ).val( $additional_copies );
            $( ':input[name="main_credits"]', $edit_row ).val( $main_credits );
        }
    };

    $( '#bulk_edit' ).live( 'click', function() {
        // define the bulk edit row
        var $bulk_row = $( '#bulk-edit' );

        // get the selected post ids that are being edited
        var $post_ids = new Array();
        $bulk_row.find( '#bulk-titles' ).children().each( function() {
            $post_ids.push( $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( /^(ttle)/i, '' ) );
        });

        // get the data
        var $additional_copies = $bulk_row.find( 'textarea[name="additional_copies"]' ).val();
        var $main_credits      = $bulk_row.find( 'textarea[name="main_credits"]' ).val();

        // save the data
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, // this is a variable that WordPress has already defined for us
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                action: 'save_bulk_edit_video', // this is the name of our WP AJAX function that we'll set up next
                post_ids: $post_ids, // and these are the 2 parameters we're passing to our function
                additional_copies: $additional_copies,
                main_credits: $main_credits
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**File `video-quick-edit.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 *  Quick Edit and Bulk Edit helper for Media Burn video records
 *
 *  @author Michael Cannon <mc@aihr.us>
 *  @ref http://rachelcarden.com/2012/03/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/
 */

add_action( 'bulk_edit_custom_box', 'quick_edit_custom_box_video', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', 'quick_edit_custom_box_video', 10, 2 );

function quick_edit_custom_box_video( $column_name, $post_type ) {
    $slug = 'video';
    if ( $slug !== $post_type )
        return;

    if ( ! in_array( $column_name, array( 'additional_copies', 'main_credits' ) ) )
        return;

    static $printNonce = true;
    if ( $printNonce ) {
        $printNonce = false;
        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'video_edit_nonce' );
    }

?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right inline-edit-video">
      <div class="inline-edit-col inline-edit-<?php echo $column_name ?>">
        <label class="inline-edit-group">
        <?php
    switch ( $column_name ) {
    case 'additional_copies':
?>
            <span class="title">Additional Copies</span>
            <textarea cols="22" rows="1" name="additional_copies" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
            <?php
        break;
    case 'main_credits':
?>
            <span class="title">Main Credits</span>
            <textarea cols="22" rows="1" name="main_credits" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
            <?php
        break;
    }
?>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'save_video_meta' );

function save_video_meta( $post_id ) {
    // TODO make $slug static
    $slug = 'video';
    if ( $slug !== $_POST['post_type'] )
        return;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && 'revision' == $post->post_type )
        return;

    $_POST += array( "{$slug}_edit_nonce" => '' );
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST["{$slug}_edit_nonce"], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['additional_copies'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'additional_copies', wp_kses_post( $_REQUEST['additional_copies'] ) );

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['main_credits'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'main_credits', wp_kses_post( $_REQUEST['main_credits'] ) );
}


add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-edit.php', 'admin_edit_video_foot' );
function admin_edit_video_foot() {
    $slug = 'video';
    // load only when editing a video
    if ( ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $slug == $_GET['page'] )
        || ( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $slug == $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-quick-edit-video', get_template_directory_uri() . '/functions/user/custom/fitv/quick_edit.js', array( 'jquery', 'inline-edit-post' ), '', true );
    }
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_bulk_edit_video', 'save_bulk_edit_video' );
function save_bulk_edit_video() {
    $post_ids          = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] : array();
    $additional_copies = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'additional_copies' ] ) ) ? wp_kses_post( $_POST[ 'additional_copies' ] ) : null;
    $main_credits      = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'main_credits' ] ) ) ? wp_kses_post( $_POST[ 'main_credits' ] ) : null;

    if ( ! empty( $post_ids ) && is_array( $post_ids ) ) {
        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'additional_copies', $additional_copies );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'main_credits', $main_credits );
        }
    }

    die();
}


?>
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It is a link to another post on the network but the answer should still stand on its own. Otherwise, just post a comment.