# Hook into admin post list page

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

So I want to create a custom admin interface for the post and page lists.  I want it to be a split view with a list of posts and some data on the left, and a full editable preview of the post on the right.  I'm having a hard time finding the right place to hook in to accomplish this.  What hooks are available for these pages?

[image]

I essentially want to hook into these screens to edit the output of them.  All I'm looking for  is a hook that will pass in all the information on this page, and allow me to output my own HTML and CSS.  I plan on making this list 50% of the screen, and when you click on one of the items, it uses ajax to pull down the post content and display it in a preview window on the right side of the screen.  Think Mac mail app.  All I'm looking for is the right hook.  I think I've got it past that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot and explanation I guess I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

### Concept

Point is, that the question is more a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What I'd recommend is changing the idea and use as much of what is available per default: The **Quick Edit** box.

### Quick Edit

The default hook to extend quick edit is `quick_edit_custom_box`. It has two arguments: The `$colName` and the `$postType`. Use that to extend the quick edit box. An example including the needed Javascript for the AJAX save action [an be found in that answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/quick-edit-screen-customization), or [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/how-to-show-a-custom-meta-box-on-the-quick-edit-screen) as well in [that answer by Frank](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71199/how-can-i-extend-quick-edit-option-with-2-more-fields).

### Javascript

The global `inlineEditPost` JavaScript object holds all the actions you need. Just `console.log( inlineEditPost );` in your console on a post admin list screen to see the list of available functions:

- `edit: function (id) {`
- `getId: function (o) {`
- `init: function (){`
- `revert: function (){`
- `save: function (id) {`
- `setBulk: function (){`
- `toggle: function (el){`
- `type: "post"`
- `what: "#post-"`

### Saving

The save action happens during `edit_post` hook. In there you should check `$_POST['is_quickedit']` to be set. From there on you can process the saving of all your data fields.

### Moving Quick Edit to a new location

The main goal of all above things is to build your new UI. After you have done that, you might want to limit the table width to 50% (`class="wp-list-table"`) and insert your altered quick edit box on the other 50% of the screen.

**Edit** Found out that it's actually easier to extend the core jQuery function.

```
( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";


    var id = '',
        rowData = '',
        $wpInlineEditPost = inlineEditPost.edit;

    inlineEditPost.customFunction= function( id ) {
        var $this = this;

        // Working with promises to bubble event later than core.
        $.when( inlineEditPost ).then( function() {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    $( '#edit-' + id ).insertAfter( $( '.wp-list-table' );
                }, 0 );
            } );
    }

    inlineEditPost.edit = function( id ) {
        var $this = this;

        // Run WP core first. Do not unbind from core.
        $wpInlineEditPost.apply( $this, arguments );

        // Run our custom function
        $this.customFunction( id );
    };
} )( jQuery || {} );
```

If you managed the last part it would be nice if you edit my answer and add in the missing piece (moving the box) as I got no test system at the moment.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks!  I'll look into this later on today after I finish up the project I'm working on.  I'll definitely update your answer.   I plan on packaging this into a plugin for download as well for anyone interested.