# Add quick edit fields without custom colum

Tags: filters, columns, quick-edit

This question is a follow up [on that answer I wrote](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116050/hook-into-admin-post-list-page/116053#116053).

Let's say I want to add something to the quick edit box for the *Posts* post type list table. To do so, I have to add a custom column because of the following part in the `class-wp-posts-list-table.php` file in core:

```
foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_display_name ) {
    if ( isset( $core_columns[$column_name] ) )
        continue;
    do_action( $bulk ? 'bulk_edit_custom_box' : 'quick_edit_custom_box', $column_name, $screen->post_type );
}
```

As you can see, the filter for custom quick/bulk edit fields won't trigger if there's no custom column registered. Now [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71199/how-can-i-extend-quick-edit-option-with-2-more-fields), [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/quick-edit-screen-customization) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/how-to-show-a-custom-meta-box-on-the-quick-edit-screen) answer suggest to either just add or add and then remove a dummy custom column.

So I added a dummy custom column:

```
$pt = 'post';
add_filter( "manage_{$pt}_posts_columns", array( $this, 'addColDummy' ) );
# add_action( "manage_{$pt}_posts_custom_column", array( $this, 'removeColDummy' ), 10, 2 );
# add_filter( "manage_edit-{$pt}_columns", array( $this, 'remove' ) );
```

Problem now is: If I then remove the custom column again from within one of those two filters above, the custom code doesn't get triggered anymore. *Question:* How can I remove the dummy column without removing the custom quick edit stuff again?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just hide the column from view using CSS ?

```
.column-yourcolumnname {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Because it would still be visible if you turn off CSS. Same reason for JS hiding.