# How to get current post ID in quick edit callback

Tags: get-posts, quick-edit

This question is related [to another previously asked question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116090/add-quick-edit-fields-without-custom-colum), which is a follow up on an answer.

## Task

As I want to extend QuickEdit to be something really awesome (and more than just *quick edit*), I need the ID of the currently "quick edited" post in my callbacks.

### Core MarkUp

From what I can see in core in the `class-wp-posts/terms-list-table.php` file and the `WP_*_List_Table#inline_edit()` function, there're no values for checkboxes, input fields, etc. set via PHP. All are set via JavaScript. The structure looks like that:

```
<!--
The post list & the inline edit markup row that gets moved
based on what post we currently edit
-->
<form id="posts-filter" action method="get">
    <table class="wp-list-table ...">
        <tbody id="the-list">
            <tr id="post-{$ID}">Post Data</tr>
            <tr id="post-{$ID}">another post... etc.</tr>
            <!-- ... even more posts -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--
    Here goes the edit row. 
    It's filled, edited and moved dynmically.
    -->
    <tr id="edit-{$currently_edited_post_ID}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
</form>
<form method="get" action>
    <table style="display:none;">
        <tbody id="inlineedit">
            <tr id="inline-edit">
                <!--
                Here are the default quick edit boxes
                as well as all custom boxes.
                You'll have to add a custom columns as well - see other question.
                -->
            </tr>
            <tr id="bulk-edit"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

### Custom Quick Edit fields

Depending on what and on which list table (post/term) we want to add custom quick edit boxes to, we need to add callbacks to filters. Again, those only work if we got a custom column (see other question).

```
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', array( $this, 'addFields' ), 10, 3 );
# add_action( 'bulk_edit_custom_box', array( $this, 'addFields' ), 10, 2 );
```

The callback itself has the actual ***problem I'm facing***. We have two (or in case of terms, three) arguments: `$postType` and `$columnName`. Both doesn't help me to retrieve the actual `$post_ID`, which I'd need for stuff like the `wp_editor()` for example.

```
public function addFields( $colName, $postType, $taxonomy = '' )
{
    // How to retrieve the ID of the currently quick edited post in here?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the ID per JavaScript from the quick edit screen’s parent `tr`: that has an attribute `id="edit-418"`, where `418` is the post ID.

So extract this number, get the post data per AJAX, and insert the values you need. Not elegant.

Read `wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js` to see how the core does it.

Comment: I've given up. And yes that's what core is doing and me as well. +1 and marking it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is impossible to extend... Why? Because quick editing stuff (for certain post) is "hardcoded" and couldn't be extended by plugins...

To prove it lets investigate the code:

1. When you click on **Quick Edit** link, `inlineEditPost` class (in `inline-edit-post.js` file) handles it and calls [`edit` method](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js#L116). Take a look at [136 line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js#L136), here it takes post data from `#inline_{post_id}` container. As you can see, you can't extend this function...
2. `#inline_{post_id}` container is populated by [`get_inline_data($post)` function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L288). Once again there is no `do_action` or `apply_filters` calls and no chance to extend it...
3. `get_inline_data($post)` function is called by `WP_Posts_List_Table` class, which is responsible for rendering the posts table [at 608 line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L608).

It means that even if you figure out a way how to get post ID for single row quick edit action, you won't be able to do a lot with it...

---

*Only partly related edit - doesn't solve the problem.*

So if you need to pass additional data to the hidden fields, you can use the `editable_slug` filter:

```
add_filter( 'editable_slug', array( $this, 'hiddenInlineFields' ) );

/**
 * Allows to add fields to the hidden fields per post.
 * Allows inlineEditPost and other JS functions to access data from there.
 * @param string $postName
 * @return string
 */
public function hiddenInlineFields( $postName )
{
    return $postName.'</div><div class="ID">'.get_the_ID();
}
```

Comment: +1 as I completely skipped that part - haven't thought that it would be useful (which still is true). But it brought an interesting insight that I haven't known so far.