# Get post meta inline edit WordPress

Tags: quick-edit

I've noticed that `/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js` is used to retrieved the state of input in quick edit mode.

For example the following code :

```
jQuery(function() {
    if ( typeof mpIds !== 'undefined' ) {
        jQuery.each( mpIds, function(index, id) {
            jQuery("tr#edit-" + id + " .my_class" ).prop({checked: true});
            console.log( id );
        } );
    }

});
```

Cannot make this work. But when I enter my code in console it does the job so I'm a little bit lost.
How would you do to get the same behaviour for a custom input ?

Comment: I forgot to say mpIds is retrieved by a `wp_localize_script()`. I send ids.

Comment: How is your code hooked in?

Comment: `admin_enqueue_scripts` as is should be or maybe I've missed smth ?

Comment: Nope. That should be right.

Comment: what is weird is that I get my IDs in logs, I'm wondering why my prop() does not trigger.

Comment: If you are aiming to show custom field inside "Quick Edit" then please take a [look at this link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26735/show-custom-fields-in-quick-edit). It talks and provides solution on similar topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the best code but I've tested something here that works :

```
(function ($) {

    // copy of the WP inline edit post
    var wp_inline_edit = inlineEditPost.edit;

    // override
    inlineEditPost.edit = function (id) {

        // WP edit function
        wp_inline_edit.apply(this, arguments);


        // get post ID
        var post_id = 0;
        if (typeof( id ) === 'object') {
            post_id = parseInt(this.getId(id));
        }

        if (post_id > 0 && typeof mp_data !== 'undefined' && $.inArray( post_id, mp_data.ids ) > -1 ) {

            var edit_row = $('#edit-' + post_id);
            edit_row.find('.my_class').prop('checked', true);
        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

It seems you have to do it this way.