# How to add a custom field to the comments "Quick Edit" screen?

Tags: custom-field, comments, quick-edit

How do you add a custom field to the comments "Quick Edit" screen?

The code below only shows on the posts quick edit screen:

```
function tips_quick_edit_fields( $column, $post_type ) {
?>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="inline-edit-col">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured"> Is this a tip?
        </label>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
<?php
}
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box',  'tips_quick_edit_fields', 10, 2 );
```

I can't find information anywhere on how to make it appear on the comments "Quick Edit" screen though.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Does [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365150/how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-quick-edit?rq=1) help at all? It's not specific to the comment's section but you might be able to tweak the answer from there.

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at that post before posting this and still couldn't figure out how to edit the "quick edit" for comments box.

Comment: @BrianSmith it's true that you can use the `wp_comment_reply` filter to add your custom field to the inline comment editor form, but the Quick Edit is a JS feature, so I'd use PHP+JS to add the custom field - i.e. using another hook to echo the HTML in your function. After all, you'd still need to use JS to make the rest work, e.g. to auto-check the field after saving the edited comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function responsible for rendering the comments quick edit form: [wp_comment_reply](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_comment_reply/).

Looking at its code, it seems you can short-circuit it using the `wp_comment_reply` filter. That only lets you start from scratch though (e.g. you can't add to the existing form).

The only way around this that I can think of is some (unholy) code like:

```
function your_custom_quick_edit_form($content) {
    remove_filter('wp_comment_reply', 'your_custom_quick_edit_form', 10, 2);

    ob_start();
    wp_comment_reply();
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    // Do horrible stuff here with str_replace and the likes
    $content = str_replace('<fieldset class="comment-reply">', '<fieldset class="comment-reply">I shouldn\'t be here', $content);

    return $content;
}

add_filter('wp_comment_reply', 'your_custom_quick_edit_form', 10);
```

But really, you probably shouldn't do that. It seems this area of the dashboard isn't really meant for customization.